# Initialize reference variables for many objects?

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a little trouble building the grids for a Battleship game for my Java class. So far, I can easily make a `for` loop to add JPanel or JButton objects to the JFrame. However, my issue is that I'll need to use those Panels or Buttons again when playing the game (such as clicking on a button to see if your opponent put a ship on that square, et cetera). Is there a simple way in Java to initialize reference variables for a LOT of objects? Or will I have to declare all of them individually?

Comment: No kidding, and he's got some decent answers on previous questions... moving on.

Comment: In addition, consider up-voting answers that you found useful.

Comment: Will do, sorry for not following proper etiquette. Now that I have that in mind, I'll make sure to follow it more closely.

Comment: Let me commend your thoughtful responses to each answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try a multi dimensional array of JPanels (or any other object). Create an array with the same size as your grid. The line below initializes an array with 5 rows and 5 columns.

```
JPanel[][] battleField = new JPanel[5][5];
```

Use nested for loops to create the panels in the array.

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < battleField.length; rowIndex++)
{
    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < battleField[rowIndex]; cellIndex++)
    {
         battleField[rowIndex][cellIndex] = new JPanel();
    }
}
```

If you want to reference the battleField array later on you would just make it into a instance variable.

Comment: Is the layout for a 2D array (x, y), like battleField[1][2] would be position (1, 2)?

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question. Thank you so much for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 4):

For a battleship game, you most likely want to retrieve the location of a button after is has been clicked.  You can create a hashtable using your buttons as keys and the point it is located at as a value.

```
HashMap<JButton, Point> buttonMap = new HashMap<JButton, Point>();

for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++)
  {
     JButton btn = new JButton();
     btn.addActionListener(this);
     buttonMap.put(btn, new Point(x, y));
     //then add the button to your container
  }
}
```

The in your actionPerformed method you can convert the button to the point it is located at like this.

```
JButton btn = (JButton)actionEvent.getSource();
Point p = buttonMake.get(btn);
```

Of course you will need to properly handle error conditions such as source not being a button or the button not being in the map...

Comment: Oooo... I didn't know that I could do that! Thank you so much, I'll definitely be putting this into good use!

Answer (score 2):

You can always extend `JButton` to keep track of the info you need. A simple example:

```
class MyButton extends JButton{
    private MyGameInfo mygameInfo;
    private int buttonId;
    //More fields....
    //Getters/Setters
}
```

Then instead of creating and adding `JButton` objects to your layout, create `MyButton` objects(which is also a JButton so your layout will not be effected) and use its extra functionality for your game logic.

Comment: This is definitely useful for what I need, thanks a ton! I'll need to use something like this in order to get the grid location of the button, so I can tell if I hit a ship or not. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is a related [matching game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) that uses a grid of buttons. This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979) demonstrates the application of the Model–View–Controller pattern to a simple game.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty neat, and I'll have to look into possibly implementing MVC into my project!