# Initializing a grid of JButton and adding them to a JFrame

Tags: arrays, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to write a program that plays Yahtzee in a JFrame. Our teacher has a way we're supposed to write it, and it involves adding ConfigurationButtons - a class that extends JButton - to the JFRame. Here is the code I have so far:

```
builder= new PlayerPanel();

manager = new JFrame("Yahtzee!");
manager.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
manager.setLayout(new GridLayout(TOTAL, numPlayers));
manager.add(builder);
//manager.add(howManyPlayers);
manager.setSize(1200,600);
manager.setVisible(true);

private class PlayerPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final int ROWS = 18;
    private JLabel[]titles;
    private PlayerPanel()
    {
        for(int j=0;j<numPlayers;j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
            {
                fields[i][j]=new ConfigurationButton(i,j);
                manager.add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946386/initialize-reference-variables-for-many-objects) solution but it didn't work- all I get is a blank JFrame.

Comment: PlayerPanel is extending JPanel but at no point do you add anything to it. You are adding directly to the frame instead.

Comment: @Stevo I tried changing manager.add(fields[i][j]) to builder.add(fields[i][j]) but still have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to fill out your JFrame, see what I have done with the following code, and apply it to your situation.

```
JFrame manager = new JFrame("Manager");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(i + " - " + j);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ((JButton)(e.getSource())).setText("Clicked");
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
    }
}

manager.add(panel);
manager.setSize(750, 750);
manager.setVisible(true);
```

Take note of how the panel is set up in a GridLayout (as you had), but the panel is then added to the JFrame.

You should be able to build your panel based off this example, substituting your custom components where necessary.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped!